# How can I create a database on the fly with .NET Core EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm having an issue with `dotnet ef`. I'm trying to create a new database for every subdomain encountered. I've learned I can use the `_context.Database.Migrate()` here, but it seems it's only possible in the Startup & Program classes.

How can I do this when the program is running already? Since I can only get the subdomain when the app is running

Here's what I've tried:

```cs
// Db Context
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) 
{
     // _ecosystemServices.GetSubdomain gets the domain
     var subdomain = _ecosystemServices.GetSubDomain(_accessor);

     // _ecosystemServices.GetConnectionString returns the appropriate connection  string based on the subdomain
     optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_ecosystemServices.GetConnectionString(subdomain));         

     // Attempting to create the database
     _context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

But this doesn't work and I get a circular dependency error. What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With EF Core you can use one of

```
context.Database.Migrate()
```

or

```
context.Database.EnsureCreated(),
```

where `context` is `DbContext`.

Where you call any of these depends on the logic of your app, but in `OnConfiguring()` is definitely *not the right place* since when database has to be created EF first creates the model and therefore calls `OnConfiguring()`. Hence you should get stack overflow message.

As of circular dependency I cannot tell but either the C# compiler is too smart and translates possible stack overflow to circular dependency (which I doubt, frankly), or the source of the error comes from somewhere else.

You should be aware however, of the differences between `Migrate()` and `EnsureCreatd()`. The second one does not apply the migrations in your code. Here's an answer by [Rowan Miller](https://romiller.com/) to a similar question about both methods in [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/3875):

> *You would either call EnsureCreated() or Migrate(). EnsureCreated() is an alternative that completely skips the migrations pipeline and just creates a database that matches you current model. It's good for unit testing or very early prototyping, when you are happy just to delete and re-create the database when the model changes.*
>
> *You can just replace all your code with db.Database.Migrate();*